# function is sending ajax request on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have below code that runs on page load. I only want to run it when user finish up writing in textbox.

Code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#user_email").on('change keyup paste', function () {
            $.post('/users/check_email?email=' + $("#user_email").val(), function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
    });
```

Text field:

```
<%= f.email_field :email, :type=>"email" %>
```

I do not want to run it on page load but when user type something in it then it should do ajax work.

Also if user writes 1 or 3 characters it started to send ajax. I need to check email so how I can handle this use case?

**Update**

The important problem is I have saved my email in textfield, something like autofill information in forms so when page loads, it sends the ajax request and start showing the xyz email already exists in the system.
I do not want to send ajax request when page load for 1st time but I want to make it working when someone write and finishes up writing email in it.

Comment: I have updated my question and thanks for correction as well ;)

Comment: Hadn't thought of autofill, blech. :-)

Comment: @LearningROR: the edit says literally nothing more relevant about the issue itself. The code should be already working as intended, unless there is something else after the DOM is loaded that is somehow filling the input. You may add strict checks on the callback for the `change` event, but the true e-mail check should rather happen on the server side rather than on client side (eventually both). The process you may want to follow is : 1) Write (or, better, search) an e-mail regex. 2) Get the user_email value and check whether the length is more than 3. 3) Do the ajax call after both checks.

Comment: so send the ajax request after clicking on a done button as i did in my answer ^^

Comment: But why would you not want to do the ajax work on autofill? If the goal is to validate the contents of the field, why wouldn't you validate the contents even when autofilled?

Comment: @briosheje: The edit does indeed provide critical additional info: The problem is autofill. At least some browsers fire the `change` event on autofill.

Comment: Because it will always show the user that this email is already exists in the system. Think, a user saved xyz@sss.com email in field and when he comes to the website he will be shown email not exist. Its really a bad UI for user I believe. I want to fix it.

Comment: How about using `autocomplete="off"` so that the field won't show saved email address, the next time when user comes to the website.

Comment: *"and when he comes to the website he will be shown email not exist"* No, he'd been shown that it already exists (if it does). Which is correct. I would call it bad UX **not** to consistently show the validation for the current field value. But it's just an opinion.

Comment: When page first time opens up and xyz user already saved some xyz email in some other fields so my email field it automatically populates the email in the current website as well. So yes, bad UX is what you are referring to. Any proper fix to cope it?

Comment: autocomplete=true still shows the autofill value of email and password in the field. :(

Comment: it should be `autocomplete="off"` and not `autocomplete=true`

Comment: Yes but still its not working. I have mistakenly wrote autocomplete=true

Comment: Try clearing the field on DOM ready.

Comment: The worst is that it sends the ajax request 3 times......!!

Comment: Why will it send 3 times?

Answer (score -1):

Check the length of the entered value, check if it is > 3, only than send an AJAX request:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#user_email").on('keyup change', function() {
    var enteredValue = $(this).val();
    if (enteredValue.length > 3) {
      $.post('/users/check_email?email=' + enteredValue, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='user_email' type='text' />
```

Comment: The code quoted will not do what the OP says, nor does switching to `focusout` do what the OP said he/she wants to do.

Comment: The question says _when user finish up writing_, isn't that `focusout`?

Comment: It might be. It might not be, it could just be when they stop typing. Until/unless the OP shows code that actually has the problem they describe, we really can't help them. (Note that `change` will fire when the user leaves the field, no need for `focusout`, which fires even if nothing changed.)

Comment: Hmm agree with you. Apologies for jumping on to solution. Shall wait for more details from OP.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#user_email").on('change keyup paste', function () {
        $.post('/users/check_email', { email: $("#user_email").val()}, 
            function(data){
                 console.log(data);
        }).fail(function(){
              console.log("error");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Why? What did you change? Why did you change it? Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Also note that the OP's use of the callback is absolutely fine.